# How to keep duplicates from a string[] exclude words from a List and print them out

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have a `string` that I want to keep the most repetitive words. And, a `list of strings` that I want to exclude from that `string`. I'm only able to return a `bool` once I go thru the `string` and `list`, which gets the result I want. But, how can I return the `string` from that method instead of the bool? I tried the following:

```
    //Fields
    private String textOnBook = "alis and joe went to the store to buy fish and salad salad is joe favorite food";
    private List<String> excludeFromText = new List<string>() {"and", "he", "the", "to", "is"};


    public List<String> MostUsedWords(String textOnBook, List<String> excludeFromText)
    {
        var word = textOnBook.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            var result = excludeFromText.Remove(word[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        return null;
     }
```

Thanks a lot for the help, peace!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the below [approach](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2JpTaU) (which outputs `joe` and `salad`).

The two `GroupBy`s allow you to group the words and then work out how many instances there are of each word. `OrderByDescending` and `First` allows you to find the most common words. `SelectMany` then extracts those words, and `Except` excludes the specific words (e.g. `and`) that you want to exclude (the `Where` is to handle the edge case where `textOnBook` is a blank string). `string.Join` is used to show the contents of the `List<string>`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{ 
    private static List<String> excludeFromText = new List<string>() {"and", "he", "the", "to", "is"};
    private static String textOnBook = "alis and joe went to the store to buy fish and salad salad is joe favorite food";


    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", MostUsedWords(textOnBook, excludeFromText)));
    }

    public static  List<String> MostUsedWords(String textOnBook, List<String> excludeFromText)
    {
        var words = textOnBook.Split(' ');

        return words.GroupBy(z => z)
                    .GroupBy(z => z.Count())
                    .OrderByDescending(z => z.Key)
                    .First()
                    .SelectMany(z => z)
                    .Where(z => z.Length > 0)
                    .Except(excludeFromText)
                    .ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm puzzle! how did you make the conclusion of using the Lambda expression, which works?

Comment: @Jacman I suppose I tend to visualise problems in terms of sets - and thus LINQ seemed appropriate here.